# How can I split one electrical signal to 3 separate signals?

Tags: signal-processing, square

I have one Hall sender in a gearbox. It creates a square signal to the speedometer with amplitude 0\7.5V. I want to use this signal in two other places, like cruise control control unit and mini display in the instrument cluster. For the instrument cluster, the square signal should have amplitude 0\5V, for cruise - 0\12V. How can I split this signal and protect my devices, because they need different voltages, like 5,7.5 and 12 volts?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: question is more suited for https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Galvanic isolation might be needed. Can't tell because you haven't shown the input circuits that receive the 3 signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hall sensors inside a gearbox typically have open drain outputs with a pullup resistor. The comparator LM339 has an open collector output, so the output high level is defined be the voltage a resistor is connected to.

Your instrument cluster would be connected to VOUT_5 and the supply V2 can be taken from there. It is also possible, that the cluster has an internal pullup resistor and you don't need R3 at all.

The cruise input would be connected to VOUT_12.

The sensor output frequencies are normally below 20 kHz, which is not a problem for LM339.

The reference voltage is about half the input voltage range.

R4 and R5 reduce EMI emissions in the connected wires.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f50Kqp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hello. Thank you! Yes, my cluster has an internal pullup resistor. I don`t see vout for speedo (7.5V). In original scheme speedometer also has an internal pullup resistor (7.5V). I am newbie in schemes, so I don`t understand where to connect triangles on scheme :(

Comment: @dima_bogun This circuit is intended as add on module to be connected to the existing 0/7.5 signal, label V_IN in the circuit.

Comment: @dima_bogun Have a look at the datasheet of LM339. You can see the "triangles" = comparator elements there and the two connections for GND and positive supply.

Comment: I mean triangles in left bottom corner and under C2. Can I use only R5 on the way to VOUT_5 (it has an internal pullup resistor)?

Comment: Those triangles are just a bit oversized GND symbols. Connect them all to the common ground. Yes, you can use only R5.

Comment: I used your scheme and it works for me, thank you! But car voltage can be 12-14.4 Volts, I want to set amplitude of signals  on VOUT_12 from 0\12-14.4V to 0\~12. I thought, that I can use L7812ABV voltage regulator. Should I add it before LM339 or after? For LM339 I use car +15 terminal, should I use voltage regulator for power LM339?

Comment: Just add a 12 V zener diode to the output. This limits the voltage and the difference to the supply will be across R2.

Comment: How should i add a zener diode to the current circuit? Connect the cathode to R2 and the anode to the CMP2 output?

Comment: I tried to connect anode to GND and cathode to CMP2 output and it works for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With a resistor divider to reduce the Voltage, if the sensor can supply enough current. But that can't increase the Voltage.

You make amplifiers with high impedance input and lower impedance output to not disturb the signal coming out of the sensor too much. You can make one amplifier for the 12V device and use resistor dividers to lower the Voltage coming out of that for the other devices. You can use transistors or op amps / comparators. Beyond that someone kind of has to design the whole circuit for you.